# RestFB only returns current user wall entries

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, feed, restfb

I'm using RestFB to get user's wall feed and ran into an issue that only posts by current user is returned. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? The exact same query works in Facebook API Explorer so I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

```
Connection<Post> rPosts = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/feed", Post.class);
```

I have tried with both version 1.6.09 and 1.6.10 with the same results.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Are the permission sets equivalent? Check with a call to `/me/permissions` with the two access tokens you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Igy mentioned above, this was related to permission issue. In Facebook Explorer, all basic permissions are set, but in my application, it was missing permissions on friends. I thought it wasn't required since it's user wall, but I guess not.